# Add camera icon in SearchView on Android

Tags: android, icons, searchview

I´m going to try to explain, although my English is a bit bad. 
Estoy utilizando MaterialSearchView de Miguel Catalan: [MaterialSearchView](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView)
I'm new to StackOverflow and they do not let me upload images. I will try to explain it. The main screen of my application has a MaterialSearchView in the Toolbar. After pressing the search icon, it takes me to the text box where you can search
I`d like to put a camera icon to the right of the 'X' of the SerchView.

[image]

[image]

Can anybody help me? Or tell me some other search component that allows you to add icons in the search bar when searching?

**EDIT**

I have got the solution. It is not the most professional way, but it is valid.
In the SearchView control, I have put two images, one for the X to delete the searched text (The original icon stays behind the camera) and another for the camera (both invisible). 
 **layout/app_bar_home.xml**:

```
        <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgClearSearch"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_close_grease_small"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgCamera"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                />
        </com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView>
```

Then, in the java class, in the listener, we show images when the searcher is shown, and hide them when hiding the searcher.

```
    //Creamos los listeners de los buscadores
    searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    searchView.setVoiceSearch(false);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            //Cuando pulsamos en buscar
            String aa = "";

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            //Cuando teclemamos en el buscador
            String aa = "";

            if (newText.length() > 20)
                searchView.setQuery(newText.substring(0, 20), false);

            return false;
        }
    });
    searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSearchViewShown() {

            imgCamera.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imgClearSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //ImageView searchClose = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
            //searchClose.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close_white);
            Drawable closeIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_close_white);
            searchView.setCloseIcon(closeIcon);

            //Cuando mostramos el buscador
            String aa = "";
        }

        @Override
        public void onSearchViewClosed() {

            //Cuando cerramos el buscador (tras haber buscado)
            String aa = "";
            imgCamera.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            imgClearSearch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

The only problem is that the X that was displayed by default to clean the text of the searcher was still showing, so I did a little trick. I replaced the icon that came out by default with a white one, so it is not visible. I've put that on the line:

```
            Drawable closeIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_close_white);
            searchView.setCloseIcon(closeIcon);
```

Este es el resultado:
[image]

Comment: Please show what you already tried and how does it fail.

Comment: What should I do to mark my own question as resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution. It is not the most professional way, but it is valid.
In the SearchView control, I have put two images, one for the X to delete the searched text (The original icon stays behind the camera) and another for the camera (both invisible). 
 **layout/app_bar_home.xml**:

```
        <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgClearSearch"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_close_grease_small"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgCamera"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                />
        </com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView>
```

Then, in the java class, in the listener, we show images when the searcher is shown, and hide them when hiding the searcher.

```
    //Creamos los listeners de los buscadores
    searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    searchView.setVoiceSearch(false);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            //Cuando pulsamos en buscar
            String aa = "";

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            //Cuando teclemamos en el buscador
            String aa = "";

            if (newText.length() > 20)
                searchView.setQuery(newText.substring(0, 20), false);

            return false;
        }
    });
    searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSearchViewShown() {

            imgCamera.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imgClearSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //ImageView searchClose = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
            //searchClose.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close_white);
            Drawable closeIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_close_white);
            searchView.setCloseIcon(closeIcon);

            //Cuando mostramos el buscador
            String aa = "";
        }

        @Override
        public void onSearchViewClosed() {

            //Cuando cerramos el buscador (tras haber buscado)
            String aa = "";
            imgCamera.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            imgClearSearch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

The only problem is that the X that was displayed by default to clean the text of the searcher was still showing, so I did a little trick. I replaced the icon that came out by default with a white one, so it is not visible. I've put that on the line:

```
            Drawable closeIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_close_white);
            searchView.setCloseIcon(closeIcon);
```

Result in my own question

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that icon is ImageView, thus you can use:

1. searchView.findViewById(id)  (ID would have to be reverse engineered)
2. searchView.GetChildAt(int position which you need to guess); (position should be somewhere between 1-5)